# ¿Cómo puedo pasarle una propiedad a un componente en react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de enviarle una propiedad al componente `Editproduct`, pero cuando lo recibo allá con `props.variable`, no me aparece el valor de la variable, hago un `console.log` y me aparece *undefined*.

```
const Home = (props) =>{

const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

function handleButtonClick(){
    setButtonClicked(true)
}

return(

<Button 
     onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}
     entry = {index}>
     <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small"/>
</Button>

   {buttonClicked ? <Redirect to="/editproduct"><Editproduct variable={true}/></Redirect> : null}
);}
```

El valor de la propiedad 'Variable' que es true, necesito recibirlo en el componente Editproduct. Al recibirlo, lo almaceno en un Hook en la función `useEffect()` y hago un `console.log` y me aparece undefined, no entiendo qué está sucediendo.

```
const Editproduct = (props) => {

   const [variable, setVariable] = useState('');

   useEffect(() => {
      setVariable(props.variable);
      console.log(variable);
   }, []);
}
```

¿Cómo hago para que me aparezca el valor de variable en el otro componente?

Comment: podrías mostrar que sale con `console.log(props)`?

Answer (score 1):

No sé mucho de React pero creo que necesitas usar `this` de la siguiente manera: `this.props.variable`. Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Esto estaría correcto si estuviera usando React con clases, pero esta usando hooks

Answer (score 0):

No está mal lo que hiciste sino que dentro del `useEffect` no está cambiando el valor del estado, si lo hacés por fuera te debería mostrar ese valor.

```
const Editproduct = (props) => {

   const [variable, setVariable] = useState('');

   useEffect(() => {
      setVariable(props.variable);
   }, []);

   console.log(variable);
}
```

> Para el caso este no hace falta que crees un estado de la misma variable, el componente va a renderizar por cada vez que cambie la propiedad, por la cual es innecesario que uses el hook de `useState` y `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

no me queda muy claro porque no tienes definida la variable en el padre, que es el componente Home. Quieres cambiar el valor de la "variable" en el componente hijo, "EditProduct" y actualizar el padre ?

```html
const Home = (props) =>{

const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
const [variable, setVariable] = useState(false);
function handleButtonClick(){
    setButtonClicked(true)
}
function handleVariable(value){
    setVariable(value)
}

return(

<Button 
     onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}
     entry = {index}>
     <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small"/>
</Button>

   {buttonClicked && <Redirect to="/editproduct"><Editproduct handleVariable={handleVariable}/></Redirect>}



y en el hijo 

const Editproduct = (props) => {

 <button onClick={()=> props.handleVariable(true)} >Click to change component father state</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la única función que vas a hacer con el botón es redirigir a otro componente lo puedes hacer usando un [Link](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/) así:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = props => {
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

function handleButtonClick() {
  setButtonClicked(true);
}

return (
  <Button          
      component={Link}
      to={{
         pathname: '/editproduct',
         state: { Variable: true }
      }}
      entry={index}
   >
      <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small" />
   </Button>
 );
};
```

Y para recibir la prop en Editproduct usas el [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation) como en el siguiente codigo:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Editproduct = () => {

   const [variable, setVariable] = useState('');

   useEffect(() => {
      setVariable(useLocation().state.variable);
      console.log(variable);
   }, []);
}
```

por si lo quieres hacer de la forma que lo tenías

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = props => {
   const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

   function handleButtonClick() {
      setButtonClicked(true);
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <Button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()} entry={index}>
            <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small" />
         </Button>

         {buttonClicked ? (
            <Redirect
               to={{
                  pathname: '/editproduct',
                  state: { Variable: true }
               }}
            />

         ) : null}
      </div>
   );
};
```